# Excel Microsoft Query Multiple Values Parameters, Bad Parameter type

Tags: excel, parameters, ms-query

I'm using office 365.
In excel I import data from Microsoft Query.
[image]

My problem is that I want to have multiple values in parameter (range) (like a IN condition), I'm only able to get the parameter from cell for only a single value.

Sample Query:

```
SELECT * FROM F4211 WHERE SDLNTY = ? AND SDCO IN ?
```

In the above query the parameter selection from cell works fine for `SDLNTY`, since its a single value. But for `SDCO` can have a multiple values, but it does not work.

Error:
[image]

What I tried:
Values:

> 19152, 19153, 19154
>
> (19152, 19153, 19154)
>
> [image]